# Match %, avoid match of \%

Tags: python, python-re

I am trying to remove comments from my TeX code. I want to trim text after `%`, but want to avoid the escaped `\%`.
I thought that this would do it

```py
re.sub(r"([^%]*)([^\\][%])(.*)$", r"\1", "10 \% foo.% bar")
```

which outputs the almost right

```
'10 \\% foo'
```

expected output:

```
'10 \\% foo.'
```

**Why does it trim away the last character before `%`?** And, how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is your regex matches [zero or more non-percent characters (group 1)], then it matches [**a non-backslash character** and a percent character (group 2)].

You replace this entire match with the first group, so you miss out the non-backslash character in group 2

Instead, use a [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), which only matches percent characters without a backslash before them, and then everything until the rest of the line [Try it](https://regex101.com/r/BamfvO/2):

```
(?<!\\)%.*$
```

In python:

```py
>>> re.sub(r"(?<!\\)%.*$", "", "10 \% foo.% bar")
'10 \\% foo.'
```

With a multi-line string, use the `re.M` flag:

```
>>> ss = """10 \% foo.% bar"
Hello world
Hello world % this is a comment
% This is also a comment
"""
>>> print(re.sub(r"(?<!\\)%.*$", "", ss, flags=re.M))
10 \% foo.
Hello world
Hello world
```

Comment: @d.b. presumably OP split their text into lines already, but I added the `re.M` flag for multiline strings so that `$` matches EOL

Comment: @d.b `[$|\n]` matches the _character `$`_ or a newline, which is not what we want. Latex comments last the rest of the line, until a newline character is seen, so we want to match until the or until the end of the string or the next newline (which is what the bare `$` does in a multiline string). Moreover, getting rid of newlines like this would mangle any multiline strings by joining a line that contains a comment with the next line

Comment: Thanks! The comments about splitting in lines are right, but that doesn't make the answer any less good.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookbehind to ensure that you're matching only `%` and not `\%`.

```
(?<!\\)%.*
```

See the `re` docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: Thanks! That is indeed what was the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the `.` with a `\`, from:

```
re.sub(r"([^%]*)([^\\][%])(.*)$", r"\1", "10 \% foo.% bar")
```

to:

```
re.sub(r"([^%]*)([^\\][%])(.*)$", r"\1", "10 \% foo\.% bar")
```

Comment: Thanks. However, this does not really answer my question (why), nor attains my goal (find a pattern that strips just what it should strip given any valid TeX code).

Comment: @TomdeGeus Can you post the text you are working on as a string?